# Javascript pushing element in array like chasing tail

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, iteration

I'd like to get output from input.
It should be pushed element like chasing tails and it couldn't be duplicated.
The rule is very simple.
Firstly, if there is the same element with input[0][1] in input[i][0],
you can put the first value of the element in a result.
The element is [1,5] so result becomes [[0,1]].
Now you can just repeat. The first element of [5,29] is the same element with [1,5][1] and result becomes [[0,1,5]]

I've been really frustrating for few weeks to solve this issue. Please help. Any comments would be appreciated.

```
input = 
[
  [ 0, 1 ],   [ 0, 2 ],   [ 0, 3 ],
  [ 0, 4 ],   [ 1, 5 ],   [ 2, 6 ],
  [ 3, 7 ],   [ 4, 10 ],  [ 4, 11 ],
  [ 4, 12 ],  [ 4, 13 ],  [ 5, 29 ],
  [ 6, 29 ],  [ 7, 8 ],   [ 8, 29 ],
  [ 9, 29 ],  [ 12, 18 ], [ 13, 19 ],
  [ 17, 29 ], [ 18, 29 ], [ 19, 29 ],
  [ 21, 29 ], [ 24, 29 ], [ 26, 29 ],
  [ 28, 29 ]
]

output = [
 [0,1,5,29],[0,2,6,29],[0,3,7,8,29],[0,4,10],[0,4,11],
 [0,4,12,18,29],[0,4,13,19,29]
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: What have you tried to do ? What is `i` ? Stackoverflow might not be the place you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can write `solver` as a generator with an input of `t` and a starting query of `q`. Other answers suggest reshaping your input or other functional techniques that iterate over the input multiple times. This simple imperative-style technique uses only one pass (per recursive call). The use of a generator allows you to find all solutions, but can be paused/stopped at any time, for any other reason -

```js
function* solver (t, q) {
  let atLeastOnce = false
  for (const [parent, child] of t) {
    if (parent == q) {
      atLeastOnce = true
      for (const sln of solver(t, child))
        yield [parent, ...sln]
    }
  }
  if (!atLeastOnce) {
    yield [q]
  }
}

const input =
  [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[1,5],[2,6],[3,7],[4,10],[4,11],[4,12],[4,13],[5,29],[6,29],[7,8],[8,29],[9,29],[12,18],[13,19],[17,29],[18,29],[19,29],[21,29],[24,29],[26,29],[28,29]]

for (const sln of solver(input, 0))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(sln))
```

```js
[0,1,5,29]
[0,2,6,29]
[0,3,7,8,29]
[0,4,10]
[0,4,11]
[0,4,12,18,29]
[0,4,13,19,29]
```

Generators are [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) and so you can collect all results in an array using `Array.from` -

```js
const all = Array.from(solver(input, 0))
console.log(all)
```

```js
[
  [0,1,5,29],
  [0,2,6,29],
  [0,3,7,8,29],
  [0,4,10],
  [0,4,11],
  [0,4,12,18,29],
  [0,4,13,19,29],
]
```

Combine generators with an optimized input type for even better results.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I've never thought using generator to solve this issue. It looks amazing. Thanks for introducing a new way!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I understood your output, what you want is kind of like a domino-chain. You seed the output with arrays start contain `0` in the first element, e.g. `[0,1]` and `[0,2]`..., and then you simply find the next array to join to the chain based on the last item in the array vs the first item in the next entry.

This process is **recursive** in nature, since you start with the seeds and have no idea how far/deep you will need to join. To break this down, we can do this:

1. Separate your `input` into seeds and non-seeds (nodes).
2. Start with seeds
3. Iterate through the seeds and invoke a function, that will recursively add nodes to your seed. The trick is that you want to duplicate the seed array, when **multiple** paths can be found

The function should invoke itself recursively, and here's a quick logic:

```
/**
 * @method
 * @params arr    The seed array (which will grow in length)
 * @params nodes  The collection of non-seeds
 */
function chain(arr, nodes) {
  // We first find whatever nodes left that we can domino-chain to the current seed
  const nextNodes = nodes.filter(node => node[0] === arr[arr.length - 1]);

  // If nothing is to be found, return the array
  if (!nextNodes.length) return [arr];

  // Otherwise we go through all the next nodes and create a copy of the current seed
  // And then append the next node to it
  return nextNodes.map(nextNode => {
    return chain([...arr, nextNode[1]], nodes);
  }).flat();
}
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const input = [
  [0, 1],
  [0, 2],
  [0, 3],
  [0, 4],
  [1, 5],
  [2, 6],
  [3, 7],
  [4, 10],
  [4, 11],
  [4, 12],
  [4, 13],
  [5, 29],
  [6, 29],
  [7, 8],
  [8, 29],
  [9, 29],
  [12, 18],
  [13, 19],
  [17, 29],
  [18, 29],
  [19, 29],
  [21, 29],
  [24, 29],
  [26, 29],
  [28, 29]
];

const seeds = input.filter(entry => entry[0] === 0);
const nodes = input.filter(entry => entry[0] !== 0);

function chain(arr, nodes) {
  const nextNodes = nodes.filter(node => node[0] === arr[arr.length - 1]);

  if (!nextNodes.length) return [arr];

  return nextNodes.map(nextNode => {
    return chain([...arr, nextNode[1]], nodes);
  }).flat();
}

const output = seeds.map(seed => {
  return chain(seed, nodes);
}).flat();

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I've been having a hard time with using recursion. Your clear code and detailed description really helps me a lot. Thank you so much! Have a good weekend!!

Answer (score 0):

I would split the problem in 2:

1. Create a tree-like structure from your list. Each node in your tree contains a reference to all possible next nodes.
2. Write a recursive function that walks the tree to find all possible paths

Here's an implementation of that approach:

```js
const input = 
  [
    [ 0, 1 ],   [ 0, 2 ],   [ 0, 3 ],
    [ 0, 4 ],   [ 1, 5 ],   [ 2, 6 ],
    [ 3, 7 ],   [ 4, 10 ],  [ 4, 11 ],
    [ 4, 12 ],  [ 4, 13 ],  [ 5, 29 ],
    [ 6, 29 ],  [ 7, 8 ],   [ 8, 29 ],
    [ 9, 29 ],  [ 12, 18 ], [ 13, 19 ],
    [ 17, 29 ], [ 18, 29 ], [ 19, 29 ],
    [ 21, 29 ], [ 24, 29 ], [ 26, 29 ],
    [ 28, 29 ]
  ];
  
  
  
const nodes = {};

// Store all paths between nodes
for (const [ start, end ] of input) {
  nodes[end] = nodes[end] || { id: end, children: [] };
  nodes[start] = nodes[start] || { id: start, children: [] };
  
  nodes[start].children.push(nodes[end]);
}

// Find all paths from 0
const getPaths = ({ children, id }) => children.length === 0
  ? [[ id ]]
  : children.flatMap(
      n => getPaths(n).map(p => [ id, ...p ])
    )

console.log(getPaths(nodes[0]));
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. 
Yes, it needs recursion and structure like tree. Code looks very clear though you said it might be needed refactoring.
Thank you so much! Have a good weekend!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a single loop too, and follow your rules:

1. if `edge` starts (`start`) with `0`, just push it into the `result`
2. otherwise try finding an already existing `path` in `result` which contains `start`
3. if the existing `path` ends with the `start`, just append `edge`'s ending location
4. if the existing `path` contains the `start` somewhere inside, put a copy of `path` up to that `position` into `result`, and append `edge`'s ending location.

```js
let input = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 10], [4, 11],
            [4, 12], [4, 13], [5, 29], [6, 29], [7, 8], [8, 29], [9, 29], [12, 18],
            [13, 19], [17, 29], [18, 29], [19, 29], [21, 29], [24, 29], [26, 29],
            [28, 29]];

let result = [];
for (let edge of input) {
  let start = edge[0];
  if (start === 0) {                            // <--- 1. (0 => push for sure)
    result.push(edge);
  } else {
    for (let path of result) {
      let position = path.indexOf(start);
      if (position > 0) {                       // <--- 2. (can't be 0, but >= would work too)
        if (position !== path.length - 1) {     // <--- 4. (need a copy)
          path = path.slice(0, position + 1);
          result.push(path);
        }
        path.push(edge[1]);                     // <--- 3. 4. (whatever path is)
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

(`JSON.stringify()` is just used for formatting)

Comment: I really appreciate your help! Using Iteration is more comfortable for me than using recursion. So your code is very helpful for me. Thank you so much!